# How can get list of shared folders on network of a target (pc/server) and put in variable? Batch

Tags: batch-file

Iam try to get a list of shared folders (with spaces) of server, and put into a variable.

My Local Network

- \\Server\Movies Action
- \\Server\Documents and Images
- \\Server\Games Action

I Have a code, but cant get full name.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in  ('net view \\Server ^| findstr /L /C:"Disc"') do (
echo %%a
)
```

Only give me :

- Movies
- Documents
- Games

Need the give full name with spaces.
Who can help me?

Comment: You specify `delims= `, rather _space_ as a delimiter; this is truncating all fields that have a space in the name.

Comment: Without delims = @echo off
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in  ('net view \\server ^| findstr /L /C:"Disco"') do (echo %%a). Then give same, only first name.